# Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me align the my login form and telephone number on this site: the page is based on 960 grid system and I need to align the left hand side client login and the phone number which is far right.

The CSS is as follows for that section:

```
#top_bar{ min-width:960px; background: #3a3a3a url(../images/menu-background-2.png) repeat-x top;   height:50px;  }
#login_bar{height:53px;}
#client_login{height:53px; width:280px; float:left; background:url(../images/client_login2.png) no-repeat center; float:left;}
#client_login_form{padding:14px 0 0 91px;}
#client_login_form input{border:medium none; outline:medium none; background:none; width:125px; height:20px; padding-right:5px; text-align:center;}
#client_login_form input.submit{width:35px;}
/*#phone{height:21px;   padding:16px 0 16px 40px; float:right;  background:url(../images/phone_icon.png) *no-repeat left; float:right;  color:#fff; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;}*/
#phone{height:21px; width:144px; padding:16px 0 16px 40px; background:url('../images/phone_icon.png') no-repeat left;float:right; color:#fff; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;}
```

I'm just not sure as to how it is done.

Thanks!

Comment: can you be more specific? How do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your login image to show correctly you need to change your css to:

```
#client_login {
    background: url("../images/client_login2.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 53px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
```

To fix your form inputs change your css to:

```
#client_login_form input {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 125px;
}
```

You will have to tweak this to get it perfect, but this should help you.  Make sure you're using [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com) to debug your site, it makes things way easier.

Comment: Cheers...what about #phone, can you help with that also :)

Comment: That one looks fine on my browser(firefox) but if it's weird in IE try adding "position: relative;" to the css.

Comment: Hi, applied the above...but if you view again form is still to the left. Thanks

Comment: It looks good on my screen.  What browser are you using to test?

Comment: Same as me.  Did you try clearing your cache after you made the change?

Comment: yeah totally.  can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Ah okay well client login should be aligned with Lorem Ipsum, so the 'c' in client login is aligned to the 'L' and then the last digit in the phone number should be aligned to 'e' in the last menu item HOME, thanks

Comment: To do that add the containit class to the #login_bar div: '<div class="page_span containit" id="login_bar">'

Then use the left/right properties on client_login/phone to align them correctly (left: -10px; for #client_login I believe)

Comment: Just to clarify I have amended the HTML to change the form code to <div class="page_span containit" id="login_bar"> and I have added left: -10px to #client_login and right: -10px to #phone only, is that correct? thanks

Comment: Yes, but the -10px values may have to be changed.  I would tweak them until those 2 elements are aligned perfectly.

Comment: Cheers, will try that now and see what you think :)

Comment: That did it and I cannot thank you enough for spending the time assisting me with that...the only last issue is if you click on the login forms the cursor appears to be in the middle...any thoughts on how to fix please?

Comment: that's just because you have the text-align on the form inputs set to center.  change that to left and you should be set :-) glad to have helped! please hit answer if it did answer this question for ya.

Comment: Awesome!  Very happy to have helped!  The answer button is a check under the voting arrows.